# How to remove a list item if it is below a certain value?

Tags: python, list

Let's say I have a list

```
a = [100, 78, -5, 0, 10]
```

How would I remove the items that are below or equal to zero. I tried using the filter but that removed only the items that **weren't** a certain value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Filter the list with a list comprehension and keep everything above zero:

```
a = [i for i in a if i > 0]
```

This creates a new list object, replacing the previous one. If you have multiple references to the list that need to see the changes, assign to a slice:

```
a[:] = [i for i in a if i > 0]
```

Now the contents of `a` are replaced by the contents of the list comprehension result.

Answer (score 0):

You would need a lambda with filter :

```
 filter(lambda x: x>0)
```